# Aligning heaps in Fibonacci heaps

Tags: trees

I'm trying to align various heaps to make a Fibonnaci heap. I'm using the package `tikz`, and also using the instruction `begin{scope}` after `begin{tikzpicture}` to align various heaps. I managed to align 3 of them, but for some reason, when I try to align 4 of them, I can't. Here's the code for just the Fibonacci heap (Overleaf says I'm ending `\begin{tikzpicture}` with a `end{scope}`, but I don't see it that way):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    level distance=10mm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=2mm}, 
    thick, every node/.style = {draw, circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.7em},
    min/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!20, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
]

\node[min]{5}

\begin{scope}
[
xshift=3.5cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=24mm}
]
 
\node[root]{11}
child{node{70}};

\begin{scope}
[
xshift=4.5cm,
level distance=10mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=23mm}, 
level 2/.style={sibling distance=14mm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=11mm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=8mm},
thick, every node/.style = {draw, circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.7em},
root/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
min/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!20, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
marked/.style={circle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm}
]
                
\node[root]{7}
child{node[marked]{15} 
    child{node[marked]{30}
        child{node{61}}}
    child{node{20}}}
child{node{9}
    child{node{11}}}
child{node{13}};
        
\begin{scope}
[
xshift=3.5cm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=24mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=12mm}
]
            
\node[root]{8}
child{node{12}};

\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I want it to look something this way (but with more nodes at the top aligned with the others):

[image: Fibonnaci Heap]

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This may be easier with `forest`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{root/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    min/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!20, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    marked/.style={circle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    if level=1{no edge}{}, 
    if level=0{}{draw},
    if n children=0{fit=band}{},
    circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.7em,
    tier/.pgfmath=level(), s sep=.5cm
}
[
    [11, min
        [70]
    ]
    [7, root
        [15, marked
            [30, marked[61][5]][20]]
            [9[11]][13]
    ]
    [8, min
        [12]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```